# How can I select all DataFrame rows that are within a certain distance of a given value in a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, vectorization

Here is an example DataFrame which I will use to better illustrate my question:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(30, 3), columns=tuple('ABC'))
df['event'] = pd.np.nan
df.loc[10, 'event'] = 'ping'
df.loc[20, 'event'] = 'ping'
df.loc[19, 'event'] = 'pong'
```

I need to create windows of *n* rows centered around each occurrence of `ping`.

In other words, let `i` be the index of a row that contains `ping` in the `event` column.  For each `i`, I want to select `df.ix[i-n:i+n]`.

Thus, for `n=3`, I would expect the following result:

```
             A          B          C event
7    0.8295863  0.2162861  0.4856461   NaN
8     0.156646  0.4730667  0.9968878   NaN
9    0.6709413  0.4796197  0.8747416   NaN
10  0.09942329   0.154008  0.5761598  ping
11   0.7168143   0.678207  0.7281105   NaN
12   0.8915475  0.8013187  0.9049722   NaN
13   0.9545411  0.4844835  0.1645746   NaN
17   0.9909208  0.1091025  0.6582635   NaN
18   0.2536326  0.4324749  0.8001643   NaN
19   0.4734659  0.5582809  0.1221296  pong
20   0.7230407  0.6695843  0.3902591  ping
21   0.3624909  0.2685049  0.5484445   NaN
22  0.05626284  0.6113877  0.9131929   NaN
23   0.8312294  0.5694373  0.4325798   NaN

[14 rows x 4 columns]
```

A few caveats:

1. I'm looking for a **non-iterative** solution.
2. Note that there is a `pong` value around which we **do not** want to center a window.  It is captured in the result of centering around the second `ping`, however.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: 1. Sort the Dataframe; 2. Get the row number of occurences of ping; 3. Get rows around the row. Does this make sense?

Comment: @RJT, can you please elaborate?  I don't see how this relates to the my question.

Comment: sorry, I hit enter too soon. My comment was intended to ask if the steps make sense to you, and to clarify where exactly lies your problem.

Comment: Just posted an answer let me know if the window and results ranges are what you want, it can be easily modified if you want to include/exclude values

Comment: @RJT, no problem!  I'm sorry, but I'm still not seeing the light.  Why do I need to sort to get the row number of `ping`?  Can't I just do `df[df.event == 'ping'].index` ?  Also, what should I sort by?  Would you mind submitting a proper answer with a working example?

Comment: @blz I understand the problem better now. My steps assumed a iterative solution, so that's not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [17]: n = 3
```

Select an indexer that is the range of what you need, e.g. the target index +- 3 (subject to the max/min of the size of the frame). Concatenate them all, and eliminate dups.

```
In [18]: indexers = np.unique(np.concatenate([ np.arange(max(i-n,0),min(i+n,len(df))) for i in df[df.event=='ping'].index ]))

In [19]: indexers
Out[19]: array([ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22])
```

Select them.

```
In [20]: df.iloc[indexers]
Out[20]: 
             A           B          C event
7   0.03348742  0.05735324  0.1220022   NaN
8    0.9567363   0.6539097  0.8409577   NaN
9    0.3115902   0.4955503  0.1749197   NaN
10   0.6883777   0.6185107  0.7933182  ping
11   0.5185129   0.6533616  0.1569159   NaN
12   0.1196976   0.9638604  0.7318006   NaN
17  0.02897615   0.1224485  0.5706852   NaN
18  0.02409971   0.4715463  0.4587161   NaN
19   0.9070592   0.3371241  0.9543977  pong
20   0.8533369   0.7549413  0.5334882  ping
21   0.9546738   0.8203931  0.8543028   NaN
22  0.05691086   0.2402766  0.3922318   NaN
```

Note that you might need to do a `df.reset_index()` (before you select to get the actual row index position, rather than a value).

Note that their is a bug here as the setting of the 'event' column converts everything to object, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7704). You can alleviate by using `df.convert_objects()`.

Answer (score 1):

One way it could be done is with nested np.where clauses.  It's not the prettiest code, but it does the trick.

```
ping = pd.Series(np.where(df.event == 'ping', True,
                          np.where(df.event.shift(1) == 'ping', True,
                                   np.where(df.event.shift(-1) == 'ping', True, False))), index=df.index)

df[ping]
```

Can someone help me take the i=1 case to the general one?

Edit: Actually, they don't need to be nested.  This will do:

```
ping = pd.Series(np.where((df.event == 'ping') | (df.event.shift(1) == 'ping') |
                      (df.event.shift(-1) == 'ping'), True, False), index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe:

```
>>> ts, n = df['event'] == 'ping', 3
>>> idx = ts.shift(n).fillna(False)  # +n rows
>>> for j in range(-n, n):  # -n to n-1 rows
...     idx |= ts.shift(j).fillna(False)
... 
>>> df[idx]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the correct output.  I'm getting four `False`s at the beginning of the resulting Series, 3 at the end, and the rest is all `True`.

Comment: @blz you are right; I had a mistake, and fixed that

Comment: I like this solution quite a bit.  I'll keep the question open for now, but this certainly seems like a good candidate.  Thanks!